# E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

> E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   com.anonyme.anonyme.EditProfileActivity has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{44781360
>   V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-1080,1776} that was originally added here
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:352)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
>                                                                                   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:294)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.anonyme.anonyme.Fragment.ChatFragment.displayCameraPreviewImage(ChatFragment.java:1134)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.anonyme.anonyme.Fragment.ChatFragment.onActivityResult(ChatFragment.java:786)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.anonyme.anonyme.MainFragmentActivity.onActivityResult(MainFragmentActivity.java:648)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3465)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3512)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
>                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**In fragment:**

```
    private void displayCameraPreviewImage(Intent responseData){
            final Dialog dialogCamera = new Dialog(generalPropListener.getSelfContext(),
                    android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        dialogCamera.setContentView(R.layout.viewimagefullscreen);
        dialogCamera.show();
    }
```

Currently I am facing this error on `dialogCamera.show();` I read many solutions but cant figure it out where to dismiss this dialog ... and also don`t know Why i need to dismiss this dialog even i creating the instance in this method only ..

Comment: @intelliAmiya camera intent open and onActivityResult i call this function so where exactly i need to dismiss ?

Comment: You have to dismiss dialog, before activity destroys, so better check if dialog is not null and showing, dismiss it inside activity `onDestory`

Answer (score 1):

Finally I resolved my issue.. thanks for your responses .. what i need to do is following ;

1. Set dialog as global member

   `Dialog dialogCamera;`
2. Initialize in constructor

   `this.dialogCamera = new Dialog(generalPropListener.getSelfContext(),
                   android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);`
3. call show() in my action

   `private void displayCameraPreviewImage(Intent responseData){
         dialogCamera.show();
   }`
4. OnPause() i need to dismiss the dialog

   ```
   if (dialogCamera != null) {
       dialogCamera.dismiss();
   }
   ```